# How can I handle an emacs org-babel snippet triggering emacsclient

Tags: org-babel, emacsclient

I want to call an external tool which will eventually invoke $EDITOR to do its thing. However from inside an org-babel code block this fails because while executing the code block the emacs I'm running from is unable to service the edit request:

```
#+name: edit-a-file
#+header: :results output
#+begin_src sh 
  echo "test" > test.txt
  strace emacsclient -w 2 -e "(emacs-pid)"
#+end_src
```

shows:

```
...
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/user/1000/emacs/server"}, 110) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/alex/org", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55c253582000
brk(0x55c2535a3000)                     = 0x55c2535a3000
sendto(3, "-dir /home/alex/org/ -current-fr"..., 55, 0, NULL, 0) = 55
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO_OLD, "\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 0
recvfrom(3, 0x7fff08e0d420, 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
write(2, "\nServer not responding; timed ou"..., 49
Server not responding; timed out after 2 seconds) = 49
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Have I just reached a limitation of an org-babel snippet?

Comment: So using :async helps but currently ob-async is broken on the latest emacs due to https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async/issues/92